Wall moisture damage by shower. Is water coming through the grout?
I recently patched this drywall and painted it because of previous water damage. I also redid the grout you see in the picture.
In the picture, you can see how the grout (Ultracolor Plus FA) looks moist. Does it look like the water is going through the grout, and in turn damaging the drywall?


First of all, that change of plane should be caulked, not grouted.  What is the thing at the right of the pic that has a dark brown line around it?
